# Expected value of an indicator function

Tags: nonparametric, expected-value, bernoulli-distribution

We have

$$ I_i (x) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad x-h<X_i<x+h \\ 0 \quad \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Does that indicator function follow the Bernoulli distribution? If so, the expected value can be computed easily.

Comment: Since it's a random variable with two possible outcomes, it follows a Bernoulli distribution with some particular value for $p$. Calculating $p$ is not possible based only on the information given in the question. In particular we are missing what $X_i$ (probably some RV) and $h$ are (probably some constant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Ziggystar said. The answer is yes. If you know the CDF (i.e., $F$) of $X$, then $E[I(x)] = F(x+h)-F(x-h)$, which I'm sure you know.

Comment: Errr.... not quite. Your answer is correct if $X$ is a continuous random variable but not if $X$ is a discrete random variable. If the CDF is defined as $F(x) = P\{X \leq h\}$, then $$E[I(x)] = \lim_{\delta \to 0} F(x+h-\delta) - F(x-h)$$ where $\delta > 0$. Some people write the limiting value as $F((x+h)^-)$ meaning the limit as we approach the point $(x+h)$ from the left. These people also say that $F(x) = F(x^+)$ and emphasize that the CDF might be discontinuous in which case the limit from the right is larger than the limit from the left.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Good point! I assumed continuity in my answer. The interval could very well be empty for some values of x and h in the discrete case.